# Query select data for different fieldid and data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this table

```
userid       fieldid            data
1              2               123123
1              3                name
1              4              something
```

How i can select data for fieldid 2 and 3 with different aliases?

`SELECT data AS nrew FROM inf_data where fieldid ='1'` << and the other one with different alias?

i would like to get:

```
userid      nrEw(fieldid=2)             smth(fieldid=4)
1            123123                        something
```

Comment: Can you show what you want as a result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated my question

Comment: SELECT data AS nrew FROM inf_data where fieldid =2 OR fieldid=3

Comment: @lakhvirkumar i would like to get the results in separated columns

Comment: sorry did not get what do you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use join

```
select i1.data as nrew, i2.data as smth from inf_data i1 join inf_data i2 on i1.userid=i2.userid where i1.fieldid='1' and i2.fieldid='4'
```

unsure if the "on i1.userid=i2.userid" is needed and works, you could add another where statement instead:

```
select i1.data as nrew, i2.data as smth from inf_data i1 join inf_data i2  where i1.fieldid='1' and i2.fieldid='4' and i1.userid='1' and i2.userid='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when fieldid = 2 then data end) as field2,
       max(case when fieldid = 4 then data end) as field4
from t
group by id;
```